# Trying to get the number of times a sub query executes

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code to sort an array into ascending order

```
int[] array = new int[] { 4, 3, 5, 1 };
var result = array.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
                    .ThenBy(g => g.Key)
                    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

I would like to be able to count the number of steps required to complete the sort. 
The specific question I am trying to solve is this:
You are given an unordered array consisting of consecutive integers  [1, 2, 3, ..., n] without any duplicates. You are allowed to swap any two elements. You need to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the array in ascending order.

Can I find the number of swaps used by LINQ?

Is it possible to get this?

So for example if the query had to swap 4 with 1 to get 1,3,5,4 then 5 with 4 to get 1,3,4,5 then this would be 2 steps.

Comment: "count the number of steps required to complete the sort" - could you give an example output based on your array input

Comment: What do you define as "step"?

Comment: It's still unclear. You want to know the complexity of this query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm

Comment: The question I am trying to solve is this:

You are given an unordered array consisting of consecutive integers  [1, 2, 3, ..., n] without any duplicates. You are allowed to swap any two elements. You need to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the array in ascending order.

Comment: Ahhh, assuming this is homework the assignment is to implement a sorting algorithm and see how fast(minimum steps) you can make it. If that is the case, the teacher/professor doesn't want you to use LINQ.

Comment: That was what I suspected...

Comment: But if the array consist of consecutive integers than it is already in ascending order.

Comment: Well you can just implement Quicksort and then count when swapping is done. https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-9.php

Comment: What do you mean by 'count when swapping is done' ?

Comment: You need to implement a sorting algorithm and count how many operations(or "swaps") it takes for your algorithm to sort the array.

Comment: @Gribbler I deleted my previous test code. Checkout the new answer; I could not do it with linq but with our own sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Gribbler I mean you count when an item is assigned a new position in the array. This is done in one place in the algorithm linked, Im sure you can find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I came up. I couldn't find the way using it with LINQ however with our own Sorting Algorithm. I did something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObservableCollection<int> array = new ObservableCollection<int>() {4,3,1,5 };
        int steps = 0;
        array.CollectionChanged+= (sender, e) => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.Action} : {string.Join(",", array) }" );
            steps++;
        };

        bool didSwap;
        do
        {
            didSwap = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
                {
                    int temp = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;
                    didSwap = true;
                }
            }
        } while (didSwap);


        Console.WriteLine("Sorted Result :");
        foreach(var item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Total Swapps {steps / 2}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is the output:

[image]